# Deploy Hadoop program in distributed mode

Tags: hadoop

Currently, I'm using Eclipse to develop my Hadoop demo. I 've run and tested it using Hadoop standalone mode.

But now I want to compile my Hadoop demo into Jar file to deploy it in fully distributed mode like Wordcount example.

Anyone can guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on any file on Project Explorer -> Export -> Generate Runnable jar file

Select the class of the main method (used to be the Driver class).

Copy the jar file to the master node of the cluster.

Then, go to the path where hadoop is installed on the master node and run

```
bin/hadoop jar jarfile.jar /hdfs/input/path /hdfs/output/path
```

For more options and details, read [this tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html) (for the new API / YARN).

You will have to update some configuration files first, like `/etc/hosts`, setup a passwordless ssh between the cluster nodes and update some `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/...` files (in the old API at least).